# Android EditText Resize Programmatically

Tags: android, resize, android-edittext

I have a view in which I have two LinearLayouts - one with Text, EditText and a Button and one  with just Text and EditText. I am trying to get the width of the second EditText (on the second line) to match the width of the first line. I have tried making it a TableLayout instead of just using LinearLayouts and now am trying to set the width programmatically. I get the width of the first EditText and try to setWidth of the second EditText, but it doesn't change sizes.

*** JAVA RESIZE ATTEMPT ***

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

 getWidthBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText10);
 setWidthBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);

 Toast.makeText(this, "Meaured Width: " + Integer.toString(getWidthBox.getMeasuredWidth()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 Toast.makeText(this, "Get Width: " + Integer.toString(getWidthBox.getWidth()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 //Neither of these setWidth Lines Work Correctly
 setWidthBox.getLayoutParams().width=getWidthBox.getWidth();
 setWidthBox.setWidth(getWidthBox.getWidth());
}
```

*** XML LAYOUT ***

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:text="Points Allowed: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" >
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/editpencil" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Points Used: "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

*** SCREENSHOT FROM EMULATOR ***
[image: Screenshot from Emulator]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it in a bit of a different way that makes the most sense to me. What I did was get the width of the pencil button via getWidth and then set the right-padding of the LinearLayout (each row is its own LinearLayout) to the width of that button. This seems to work perfectly and allows for the button to change size (based on screen size and DP) and the padding to react accordingly.

```
imageButtonWidth = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonEdit);
linearLayoutPointsUsed= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearPointsUsed);

widthOfEditButton = imageButtonWidth.getWidth();

linearLayoutPointsUsed.setPadding(5, 0, widthOfEditButton, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to do this

```
getWidthBox.getLayoutParams().width=getWidthBox.getWidth();
 setWidthBox.setWidth(getWidthBox.getWidth());
```

Comment: The second EditText still goes to the edge of the screen.

I've attached a screenshot to the first post.

Answer (score 0):

I would just use relative layout and alignRight the second TextView to the first

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Test Text1: "
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Btn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/TV01"
        android:text="test text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="myBtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TV02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TV01"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Text2: "
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ET02"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ET01"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ET01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TV01"
        android:text="test text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide some code to help me with this? I tried putting the entire LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout and then added the alignRight code to the below - not sure why my code won't appear below.
`<EditText`
`android:id="@+id/EditText01"`
`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:layout_weight="1"`
`android:ems="10"`
`android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText10"`
`android:inputType="number" />`